# Fixed Background image position is not working in iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, background

I am setting up an image as fixed background and with position center center. Its working fine in chrome and firefox. But not working in iphone safari. Here is my css i am using

```
body.result.regifruit .container {
background: url(../img/lemon-black-background-mobile.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
}
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Thanks